Как наложить mask'у с lineargradient на path в svg
У меня есть вот такой график сделанный с помощью recharts

Сейчас у графика минимум и максимум это 4 и 10, но нет таких значений, что больше 6 в данном случае и потому градиент накладывается не совсем так, как хотелось бы. Он сейчас накладывается на текущую высоту графика, а хотелось бы, чтобы он принимал максимальную высоту, а цвет брал как маску
Выглядит это так - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/frosty-williams-htdhxd?file=%2Findex.html%3A198%2C9
Не дало вставить сюда код, слишком много символом
Не уверен, что нужно показывать, как сделан через recharts, т.к. в итоге все равно будет работа как с обычным svg
Видел решение через linearGradient который накладывается на rect (прямоугольник), а тот вставляется в , а дальше к  применяется маска, но что-то не выходит у меня
